# iOS - dealing with multiple active views

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to accomplish something and I'm not sure what the best way to do it is.  I'm transmitting and receiving data over bluetooth and that data has to be shared with a number of views at the same time, although one view will be active at any one time.  While the other views won't be visible I would need them to receive the data that is being sent over bluetooth in order to maintain the proper state.

I'm thinking that UIPageViewController is the right approach, but I'm not clear as to whether all the view controllers will be alive and working when using this model.  Alternatively I can maybe maintain the state of the ChildViewControllers in my UIPageViewController and make it act like a datasource.

My apologies if I'm not using the right vocabulary I'm still trying to get my hear around a lot of this stuff.

Comment: Why don't you put all of the received data into a custom class and then use that class in every VC?

Comment: Don't store data in views, store them in some sort of "model" object. Refresh the view when the view is made visible. Otherwise, you're just throwing away work updating the views and forcing the views to carry the burden of a model.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why I was making my life so much more complicated

Comment: @KhaledBoulos, if someone answered your question, accept their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard of MVC or Observer design pattern before ??

Represent your data state encapsulated into your model and once a UIViewController is displayed ask the current state from your model and display it there. 
[image]

Now the question is how to implement this ? 
In the above picture Door Object is data recieved from bluetooth and Listeners or Observers are your view's (i.e UIviewcontroller)

Would UIPageController do the job ??

Yes but Not the way you want to. UIpagecontroller uses lazy loading of view controllers i.e it will only load a view-controller when it is displayed or about to display.

[image]

This is what a UIPageController looks like. It is a scrollview with child view controllers. Only the visible section is loaded. So the view controllers which are loaded by user will be the only one who will receive notifications. You don't want to forcefully load all of them because its not efficient performance wise.

Proposed Solution: Use [NSNotifications](http://www.devfright.com/nsnotificationcenter-tutorial/) and make every UIView controller register to it and once your get data from bluetooth send it to view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Since some of your view controllers or views may not exist when the data is received, you need  a state object to keep the data. That object would exist for the lifetime of the app, and would be accessible by any view controller. The view controllers that need to show the data will just get it from that object.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you mean multiple active view CONTROLLERS, not views.

Those two things are **not** interchangeable. A view controller manages a view hierarchy and mediates between those views and the model data it manages.

Starting in iOS 6, it's quite easy to use storyboards to have a view controller manage a portion of the screen. You add a container view to your parent view controller, and then connect and embed segue between the container view and the view controller who's contents will be drawn there. The system then sets everything up so the child view controllers' view is installed in the parent.

A page view controller is intended for a book style interface, where the user flips between view controllers that each manage a page of content. A page view controller is rather like a table view. It has a delegate and a data source. It asks the data source to serve up view controllers for pages as needed.

I think a page view controller is intended to ask for new view controllers for each page it needs to display, and discard them when it's done with them. Thus it wouldn't be a good choice for managing a set of view controllers that "stick around".

If the number of pages you need to display is small and fixed you might be able to create view controllers for all your pages and save them into an array, and then return them to the page view controller as needed. That would keep all your individual view controllers alive as needed.

You probably want to set up a bluetooth manager singleton object that manages the bluetooth conversation with other devices, and broadcasts notifications as data comes in. That way view controllers can register for the notifications they are interested in as needed, and un-register when they no longer need to be notified. (be sure to unregister for notifications in your dealloc method or you will crash when your bluetooth manager tries to send a notification to a deallocated object.)

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to go about this is to create you custom object, or class, and store the data in there. That way it can be accessed by all ViewControllers and you aren't stuck with passing data between them and creating a memory nightmare. If you will only be adding data in once, and then using that data throughout the app, may I suggest a [singleton](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)?